# Dynamic switch in Matlab MAT file

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab mat file, which has the following variables:

```
variable0
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

Is it possible to dynamically index them and modify, something like this:

```
function setVariable(obj, variableNum, data)
    obj.matFile.(variable0+variableNum) = data;

end
```

So, if someone passes 0 variable 0 is modified and if someone passes 3 then variable three.  I know this code doesn't work, this is just some example of what I tried.  My current solution is to use a switch statement.  This is not so good as in the C++ code, I am using indexing like above.  I would like the C++ and Matlab to be as close as possible.

**ANSWER**

I did it this way and it is working:

```
eval(sprintf('obj.matfile_variable%d = data;', variableNum));
```

Comment: Do yo mean `sprintf('variable%d',variableNum)`?

Comment: But how can I use a string to call the mat file?

Comment: Do you mean how to use the string to load the mat file into a Matlab object? If so, you need `matfile(filename)` function to create an matfile object. And honestly, I don't think it would be working in just one line. You perhaps need some data checking as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setVariable(obj, variableNum, data)
    % check if variableNum is numeric
    if isnumeric(variableNum)
        variableNum = num2str(variableNum);
        varName = strcat('variable',variableNum); 
    else
        varName = strcat('variable',variableNum);
    end

    obj.matFile.(varName) = data;


end
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I know it's trivial but I'd like to mention. `num2str` actually checks the first input argument for string type and return it directly. so you don't need the `if...else...` statement. Just do the conversion and string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
obj.matFile(variableNum).data = data;
```